# Plot an arc using just direction and distance

Tags: trigonometry, graphing-functions, curves

So I'm trying to figure out how to plot a curve based on limited information. I have an object moving along a path, I know the starting position, and every 20 ft I get an update on the direction of the object's motion. By the time the object travels a certain distance I'd like to know exactly where it is relevant to the starting position. I can't figure out how to calculate that curve or the final position based on that information. Anyone have any ideas?

And yes this is for practical application. I am trying to use azimuth readings on a drilling rig to calculate the deviation of our hole so we can get a more accurate result for the end position of our hole after a set distance.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: There is insufficient information. Suppose that the reported direction is always the same. Then the trajectory might be a straight line or something else, like a spiral.

Comment: Maybe direction is the wrong term. We can measure the orientation of the object in 3d space by measuring the magnetic azimuth and inclination. But since the rod is traveling in a straight line along its orientation, I figure the orientation is analogous to its direction.